# Not able to convert SQL query in dataview Rowfilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable, rowfilter

I am trying to convert my SQL query with case when condition on rowfilter but it is not working.

This is my SQL query:

```
select * 
from myview 
where myview.CHARGE_CODE = (CASE 
                               WHEN 'ALL' = 'ALL' THEN CHARGE_CODE 
                               ELSE '1023' 
                            END)
```

and this is rowfilter query:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CHARGE_CODE=(CASE '"+ddlCharge_Code.SelectedValue +"' when 'ALL' THEN CHARGE_CODE ELSE '"+ ddlCharge_Code.SelectedValue+"' END )";
```

How do I convert my SQL query in C#?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to check the optional parameters and add them to the query, but this will work

```
var paramValue = ddlCharge_Code.SelectedValue; 
string filter = string.Format("('{0}' = 'ALL') OR ('{0}' <> 'ALL' AND  CHARGE_CODE = '{0}')", paramValue);
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't convert it in an identical way. In the MySQL query, there is a check `'ALL'='ALL'` which will allays be true. So the following statement would yield the same results as your original query:

```
select * from myview where myview.CHARGE_CODE = CHARGE_CODE
```

If you translate that to the RowFilter you defined you get:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CHARGE_CODE=CHARGE_CODE";
```

I think, that you missplaced the terms to check against. I suppose it should be:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "CHARGE_CODE='"+ddlCharge_Code.SelectedValue + "'";
```

Comment: in my sql query ALL stands for all records in the table so your query wont work here.

Comment: I have a multiple set of selection criteria where user can select All charge_code  or single so my sql queries work fine when user select all it will give all charge_code or if user select single charge_code it will give according to that.